# Initialize bean when leaving specific page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to initialize an object injected with @Autowired if it leaves the current page?

For example, if the current user uploads a photo while writing, the photo information is stored in a hashmap in the injected object.

At this time, if the user uploads a picture and cancels writing (move to another page), the injected object must be initialized. Currently, if the writing is canceled and the text is registered again, the previously stored image remains in the object.

Here is my code

> When a user registers a picture, the uploadImage receives the file as a parameter.

Controller.java

```
    @PostMapping("/image")
    public void uploadImage(@RequestPart MultipartFile upload) {
         s3Service.tempUpload(upload);
    }
```

> Transfer the file to tempUpload of s3Service object and upload it to /temp of s3 After writing is complete, save the file in the Map variable of TempImage to move the photo to the actual folder.

Service.java

```
private TempImage tempImage;

@Autowired
    public S3Service(TempImage tempImage) {
        this.tempImage = tempImage;
}

public String tempUpload(MultipartFile file) {
        s3Client.putObject(
                new PutObjectRequest(bucket + "/temp", fileName)
        );

        tempImage.setTempFile(fileName, bytes);
    }
```

TempImage.java

```
@Component
public class TempImage {

    private final HashMap<String, byte[]> tempFile = new HashMap<>();

    public HashMap<String, byte[]> getTempFile() {
        return tempFile;
    }

    public void setTempFile(String fileName, byte[] bytes) {
        this.tempFile.put(fileName, bytes);
    }

    public void clearTempFile() {
        this.tempFile.clear();
    }

}
```

At this time, if the user goes back or leaves the page, the TempImage object should be initialized.

Currently it continues to accumulate.

Comment: You are keeping state in a singleton, never do that. If you have 2 users concurrently doing this, only a single one will remain. You are solving the wrong problem. Also what you are doing is also a nice way of producing a memory-leak (or DOS attack). Upload large files, all are kept in-memory and at one point your application will blow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of spring bean scopes.

> **singleton**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to a single object instance per Spring
>   IoC container.
>
> **prototype**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to any number of object instances.
>
> **request**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a single HTTP
>   request; that is each and every HTTP request will have its own
>   instance of a bean created off the back of a single bean definition.
>   Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **session**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a HTTP Session.
>   Only valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.
>
> **global session**
>
> Scopes a single bean definition to the lifecycle of a global HTTP
>   Session. Typically only valid when used in a portlet context. Only
>   valid in the context of a web-aware Spring ApplicationContext.

Spring creates beans as singleton by default.

However, springboot/spring cannot understand if user leaves or enters a page since it is not controlled by them. You can create another service that clears all the data in TempImage by calling an api when user leaves the page.